# Middle mouse button behaviour in Iceweasel (FireFox): paste at *text* cursor

Tags: x11, gnome, mouse, firefox

In Iceweasel under Gnome on Debian Jessie, the middle mouse button exhibits the following behaviour:

1. If clicked on a hyperlink, it opens the link in a new tab.
2. If clicked anywhere in an editable text field, it pastes the contents of the `PRIMARY` X selection into the text field *at the location of the mouse cursor*, regardless of where the text cursor is.
3. If clicked on a tab, it closes that tab.
4. If clicked anywhere else in the window, then:

   1. if the `PRIMARY` X selection content is a URL, Iceweasel navigates the foreground tab to that URL.
   2. if the `PRIMARY` X selection content is *not* a URL, nothing happens.

Some of these behaviours violate the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment), at least for me.

How can I change the behaviour of the middle mouse button in Iceweasel under Gnome in Jessie, so that instead of the above:

1. If clicked on a hyperlink, it opens the link in a new tab.
2. If clicked anywhere in the window *except* on a hyperlink, while there is an active text cursor in an editable text field in that window, it pastes the contents of the `PRIMARY` X selection into that text field at the location of the *text* cursor (i.e. it mimics traditional UNIX terminal behaviour).
3. If clicked under anywhere in the window in any other circumstance, it does nothing.

Comment: You can set `middlemouse.contentLoadURL` to false to disable navigate-on-paste. I don't think you can do the rest.

Comment: @MichaelHomer, thank you for the heads-up about the `middlemouse.contentLoadURL` in Iceweasel. That's something, at least :)

Comment: That's odd. I can't reproduce it on firefox (or anything else). Middle mouse pasting should always be at the position of the text cursor.

Comment: @terdon: What? No. Middle-click paste is always at the mouse cursor for me. The only thing I can find that doesn't do that is gvim while it's in insert mode (but not normal mode). That's standard X convention as far as I know.

Comment: @MichaelHomer only if you've already added whitespace after the mouse cursor in my experience. For example, emacs (GUI) will paste at the text cursor on an empty line but on the mouse cursor if you've added enough spaces. Same for firefox here. I've never seen it work in any other way.

Comment: Oh, yes, certainly not inserting spaces - just as near to the spot as possible. I don't think that's what's being suggested here, though - sampablokuper wants pasted text to appear always at the text cursor, with no connection to the mouse cursor at all (like an xterm paste). If I middle-click at the start of this text box with the cursor here I get a paste at the beginning, not the end, but sampablokuper wants it the other way around. (I think?)

Comment: @MichaelHomer, yes, your understanding of what I'm after is correct. In my `.emacs` I have `(mouse-yank-at-point t)` for the desired effect.